# Making a snap to run on Ubuntu Touch

Tags: ubuntu-touch, compiler, snap, gps

I am looking to investigate the process of creating snap packages as detailed [here](http://snapcraft.io/create/) - but before I do - would it be possible to compile a programme - specifically FoxtrotGPS - to run on Ubuntu touch? I am not a programmer but I will have a go if this is remotely possible. I know there are other Apps such as OSMscout and Unav but these for me have proved unreliable without a sim card relying on GPS only. This would also mean I could use my pre-prepared traces and maps previously used on my EEEpc running Peppermint.

Answer (score 3):

`snapd` is not integrated with Ubuntu Touch yet, so on the phone or on the tablet, you won't be able to easily install snap packages.

That said, you can take a look at https://github.com/ubuntu/snappy-playpen/tree/master/ubuntu-clock-app to see how the Ubuntu Clock app (from the phone) was turned into a snap package, so it can be run on the Unity7 desktop.

What you are after is in the works, but it's not quite there yet. Getting your app ready to be snapped will make sense in any case.

Comment: Does Canonical ultimately want to replace click packages with snaps?

Comment: Yes, they offer much more built-in security, better build support and much more.